# Show all Items of a AngularFire2 List

Tags: angular, angularfire2

how to reset a filter or initially show all records, please ?

reference:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md#creating-a-query-with-observable-values

Example app:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable,     FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      {{ item.text }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <h4>Filter by size</h4>
    <button (click)="filterBy('small')">Small</button>
    <button (click)="filterBy('medium')">Medium</button>
    <button (click)="filterBy('large')">Large</button>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  sizeSubject: Subject<any>;

  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.sizeSubject = new Subject();

    //////////////////////////////////////////
    SHOW ALL RECORDS instead of none (at this state nothing is shown util the sizeSubject.next is set) 
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    this.items = af.database.list('/items', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'size',
        equalTo: this.sizeSubject
      }
    });

  }
  filterBy(size: string) {
    this.sizeSubject.next(size); 
  }
}
```

Comment: or better , what is the best approach ? Create another query ? Set Filter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the query to run it needs a value. Subject does not have an initial value. And thus the query will not run until you call sizeSubject.next(value).
Now to give the subject an initial value you can use BehaviorSubject instead like shown below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable }   from 'angularfire2';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    {{ item.text }}
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
    <h4>Filter by size</h4>
    <button (click)="filterBy('small')">Small</button>
    <button (click)="filterBy('medium')">Medium</button>
    <button (click)="filterBy('large')">Large</button>
</div>
`,
})
export class AppComponent {
    items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    sizeSubject: Subject<any>;

    constructor(af: AngularFire) {
        // BehaviorSubjects need an initial value. and they emit only the latest value it has to the subscriber, regardless when the subscriber subscribes.
        // So as we now create a BehaviorSubject with initial value null, null will be the latest value of the subject, untill you call this.sizeSubject.next('somevalue')
        // which will then be the emitted value from the Subject.
        this.sizeSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);

        this.items = af.database.list('/items', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'size',
                equalTo: this.sizeSubject
            }
        });

    }
    filterBy(size: string) {
        this.sizeSubject.next(size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are asking, if you read the url on your question you got this:

> ### Creating a query with observable values
>
> Rather than specifying regular values, observables can be used to
>   dynamically re-run queries when the observable emits a new value.
>
> This is the magic of AngularFire2.
>
> An RxJS Subject is imported below. A Subject is like an Observable,
>   but can multicast to many Observers. Subjects are like EventEmitters:
>   they maintain a registry of many listeners. See

So on the template just add a new button:

```
<button (click)="filterBy()">Reset filter</button>
```

And just call the `filterBy` function with no params, passing `null` or `undefined` to your filter will reset it

### Edit

For getting all the results you could use the `BehaviorSubject` as [Tony Krøger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2374893/tony-kr%C3%B8ger) suggested.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable,     FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      {{ item.text }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <h4>Filter by size</h4>
    <button (click)="filterBy('small')">Small</button>
    <button (click)="filterBy('medium')">Medium</button>
    <button (click)="filterBy('large')">Large</button>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  sizeSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.sizeSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null); // initialize the observable with a null value

    this.items = af.database.list('/items', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'size',
        equalTo: this.sizeSubject
      }
    });

  }
  filterBy(size: string) {
    this.sizeSubject.next(size); 
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works by calling filterBy but how to do that in the automatically when you start the app?
I tryed calling FilterBy() in teh constructore but as expected I get :
```
[ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
(method) AppComponent.filterBy(size: string): void
```
If i just call filterBy('') it does not work and doesnt show any items

Essentially I like to display all items when the app starts, after that the user should be able to filter them

Comment: Oh just change the filterBy function to `filterBy(size?: string) {
    this.sizeSubject.next(size); 
  }`

Comment: calling this.filterBy(null); in the constructor has no effect either

Comment: OK changed it to ```filterBy(size?: string)``` now I can call filterBy without a parameter, but when calling it in the constructor I sill get nothing shown.

Comment: here is my full code:
https://github.com/daslicht/angular2-firebase/blob/oauth/src/app/app.component.ts#L39

Comment: Have not tested, but if you want to give the subject an initial value, you could use BehaviorSubject(somevalue) instead of subject, that way you will have an initial value, and the latest value will be displayed to the subscriber.

Comment: Just tried it, it, it is the same , I just get nothing shown , or all items without an size

Comment: @TonyKrøger is right if you use the BehaviorSubject, it works . Look at my updated answer

Comment: This will return all your items: `this.sizeSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);`